# Getting error "Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I want to use angular-google-map api, but getting error : `"Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error"`

I want to test Google-map-api using browser key. I got this tutorial form [How to use google-map-key](http://www.saintsatplay.com/blog/2015/03/using-google-maps-in-angular-js#.ViZr6h8cg8q)

I tried to run but getting above error. Please see the demo for using Google-Map Key [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/1BVLyqZQVziN82Jat5Rq?p=preview)

Answer (score 3):

version 2.2.x of google maps has an additional dependency on `nemLogging`.  If you use the non-minified versions of your libraries you get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module customMap due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api.models.parent due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api.models.child due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.directives.api.utils due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.extensions due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module uiGmapgoogle-maps.providers due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module nemLogging due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'nemLogging' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

The new dependency is discussed on this [github issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1477).  I would recommend either including that new library, or using the version specified in your guide (2.0.16)

Answer (score 1):

It seems [the same issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1477) has been reported in [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) repository. The solution would be to explicitly add a reference to [angular-simple-logger](https://github.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger)

**Example**

```js
angular.module('appMaps', ['uiGmapgoogle-maps','nemLogging'])
.config(function (uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider) {
    uiGmapGoogleMapApiProvider.configure({
        //key: 'PUT YOUR KEY HERE',
        v: '3.17',
        //libraries: 'weather,geometry,visualization'
    });
})
.controller("mapController", function ($scope, uiGmapGoogleMapApi) {

    // Define variables for our Map object
    var areaLat = 44.2126995,
        areaLng = -100.2471641,
        areaZoom = 3;

    uiGmapGoogleMapApi.then(function (maps) {
        $scope.map = { center: { latitude: areaLat, longitude: areaLng }, zoom: areaZoom };
        $scope.options = { scrollwheel: false };
    });

});
```

```css
html, body, #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0px;
}

#map_canvas {
            position: relative;
}

.angular-google-map-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://rawgit.com/nmccready/angular-simple-logger/master/dist/angular-simple-logger.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-google-maps/2.2.1/angular-google-maps.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="appMaps">
    <div id="map_canvas" >
        <div ng-controller="mapController">
            <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" options="options" zoom="map.zoom"></ui-gmap-google-map>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```